# Выровнять блок в HTML

Tags: html, css

Привет всем. Помогите с элементарной вещью (сам понимаю, но сообразить не могу :=) ).
Есть форма, ее нужно расположить по центру и выровнять по правому краю. То есть чтобы все поля text располагались ровно, а текст слева от них - нет. Как-то так:  ))
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">Title 2</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">Title 3</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

.title {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.input {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Результат:  http://jsfiddle.net/n38ov7b4/

Все проще простого.  :)

Comment: спасибо огромное))